# React Native: how to pass params from one stack navigator to screens in another stack navigator?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, stack-navigator

In my React Native app, I have a component `OuterStackNavigator` which contains several screens and an `InnerStackNavigator`, which itself contains screens `Screen1` and `Screen2`. I want to pass a param from `OuterStackNavigator` to `Screen1`. I'm using react-navigation@4.0.10.

What's the best way to approach this?

Comment: Have you considered lifting state above the navigator using context or global state like redux?

Answer (score 0):

For navigating between `InnerStackNavigator` and `OuterStackNavigator` you have to create a top-level Navigator, Follow this to create a top-level navigator.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/navigating-without-navigation-prop

In this way, you can navigate between these two stacks so if you can navigate you can also pass params while navigating.